# VB Script (VBS) array reference

Tags: arrays, vbscript, reference

I have 2 arrays

```
array1 = Array("elem1", "elem2", "elem3")
array2 = Array("item1", "item2", "item3")
```

I then select one of the arrays

```
Randomize
dim refArray
if Rnd < 0.5 then
    refArray = array1
else
    refArray = array2
end if
```

And I make changes to its elements

```
refArray(0) = "foo"
refArray(1) = "bar"
```

Say Rnd is less than 0.5 and refArray = array1 executes. I would like that both array1 and refArray point to the same piece of memory, so when I make changes to refArray they should also be visible in array1.

After the code executes I would expect the contents of array1 to be: "foo", "bar", "elem3". But instead it remains unchanged.

The problem I am having is that vbs does not pass a reference to array1 or array2, but instead it duplicates it to a new array refArray, which gets the changes and leaves array 1 and 2 unchanged.

How can I get a reference to the array and have the changes made to refArray apply to the referenced object (normal Java/C usage)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to get a reference to a native VBScript array is a Sub/Function call:

```
>> Sub assignArray(a, i, e)
>>   a(i) = e
>> End Sub
>> array1 = Array("elem1", "elem2", "elem3")
>> array2 = Array("item1", "item2", "item3")
>> WScript.Echo "array1", Join(array1), "array2", Join(array2)
>> assignArray array1, 0, "abra"
>> assignArray array2, 0, "cadabra"
>> WScript.Echo "array1", Join(array1), "array2", Join(array2)
>>
array1 elem1 elem2 elem3 array2 item1 item2 item3
array1 abra elem2 elem3 array2 cadabra item2 item3
```

If that does not solve your real-world problem - btw: what **is** your real-word problem? - consider to use objects (Dictionary, System.Collections.ArrayList) instead.

**To spell it out:**

Array-assignment copies. References to (native) arrays are possible by parameter passing only. As VBscript is neither C nor Java, you'll have to adapt your 'design' to the language - e.g.:

```
Option Explicit

Sub assignArray(a, i, e)
   a(i) = e
End Sub

Randomize

Dim a1 : a1 = Split("I don't believe this")
Dim a2 : a2 = Split("solves any real-word problem")
WScript.Echo "a1:", Join(a1)
WScript.Echo "a2:", Join(a2)
If Rnd < 0.5 Then
   assignArray a1, 0, "We"
Else
   assignArray a2, 3, "problems"
End If
WScript.Echo "a1:", Join(a1)
WScript.Echo "a2:", Join(a2)
```

output:

```
a1: I don't believe this
a2: solves any real-word problem
a1: We don't believe this
a2: solves any real-word problem

a1: I don't believe this
a2: solves any real-word problem
a1: I don't believe this
a2: solves any real-word problems
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but this doesn't help me (except maybe for the suggestion to use something other than arrays). I have made changes to my original question and hope it is clearer.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to handle arrays by reference, consider using [`ArrayList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx) objects instead:

```
>>> Set a1 = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
>>> a1.Add 1
>>> a1.Add 2
>>> a1.Add 3
>>> WScript.Echo "[" & Join(a1.ToArray, ",") & "]"
[1,2,3]
>>> Set a2 = a1
>>> a2(1) = 4
>>> WScript.Echo "[" & Join(a2.ToArray, ",") & "]"
[1,4,3]
>>> WScript.Echo "[" & Join(a1.ToArray, ",") & "]"
[1,4,3]
```